# Package/procedure for causal mediation analysis with two mediators in multilevel data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mediation

I have an epidemiological cohort with multiple survey waves. The independent variable and mediators of interest are numeric and normal enough while the dependent variable (self perceived general health) is a Likert 1 to 5 scale variable. My analysis thus far has been conducted in `R` and I have been using a random slope on participant ID to account for the repeated data (`1|ID`). I started with `ordinal` and `clmm()` but have approached the mediation analysis treating the dependent as continuous to use `mediation` with `lmer()` from `lme4`.

This approach has worked for causal mediation analysis with one mediator:

```
#Example data - very fake
dat <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:50,3), 
                  gen_health=sample(1:5, 150, replace=TRUE),
                  x=rnorm(150, mean=5, sd=2.5),
                  med_1=rnorm(150, mean=6, sd=2),
                  med_2=rnorm(150, mean=4, sd=1.25),
                  covariate=rnorm(150, mean=30, sd=8))
#Packages
require(lme4)
require(mediation)

#Simple mediation via med_1
model_x_1 <- lmer(gen_health ~ x + med_1 + covariate + (1 | ID), data = dat)
model_med1 <- lmer(med_1 ~ x + covariate + (1 | ID), data = dat)
med_med_1 <- mediate(model_x_1, model_med1, treat='x', mediator='med_1')
summary(med_med_1)

#Simple mediation via med_2
model_x_2 <- lmer(gen_health ~ x + med_2 + covariate + (1 | ID), data = dat)
model_med2 <- lmer(med_2 ~ x + covariate + (1 | ID), data = dat)
med_med_2 <- mediate(model_x_2, model_med2, treat='x', mediator='med_2')
summary(med_med_2)

#Parallel mediation via both med_1 and med_2
#???? 
#Help?
```

I cannot figure out how to extend to a parallel mediation model with two mediators whilst retaining the random slope on participant ID. I would like to calculate the indirect effect via mediator 1, the indirect effect via mediator 2 and the average direct effects with 95%CIs for all. Do you have a suggestion or recommendation of how to do so? I'd prefer to stay in `R` but have access and experience to use `Stata` (also `SPSS` but I doubt that is the solution).

Comment: Could you share an example code with your question?

Comment: @AminShn I have added the code that works for the simple mediation. I have no idea how to extend it to the parallel mediation needed.